# genetic algorithm library

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

Does someone know a genetic algorithm library? Programming language is not so important. Could be C#, Python, Java, ... I would need it to find optimal decision tree solutions.

Comment: this: http://www.google.at/search?q=genetic+algorithm+library&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: I will take a look on: http://www.cpan.org/ too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pyevlove](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/)

From the website:

> Pyevolve was developed to be a complete genetic algorithm framework written in pure python.

Answer (score 1):

You will find loads in C++ and Java. JGap is good.
Entirely depends on what is your requirement in GA implementation what level and type of mutation, crossover, selection, representation strategies need to be available, etc. just google for genetic algorithms alone you will find alot in your search. You might also need to be careful of the licenses some of them are only available for research purposes only and will not scale well in production environment. Your best bet is to implement your own - some of these libraries work like CMS specfic to specific contexts and requirements they are unable to cater to everyones needs.

GA is a global optimization strategy so they can be slow to work with - I wouldn't advise you to implement such algorithms in python unless you are using externally compiled libraries - a better language would be Java or C++.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Pygene](http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/pygene/) which is really good.

Answer (score 0):

[GeneticSharp](https://github.com/giacomelli/GeneticSharp) is a good option for C#.

The library supports several kinds of populations, generation strategies, selections, crossovers, mutations, reinsertions and terminations. There are a lot of these classic methods already implemented, like: roulette wheel selection, tournament selection, OX1 crossover, PMX crossover, RSM mutation, uniform mutation, elitist reinsertion, pure reinsertion, time evolving termination, fitness stagnation termination, etc.

You can extend the library for your need just implementing new classes of the available  interfaces of classic GAs method.

The library also supports .NET and Mono.

Answer (score 0):

DEAP is a python package that allows for all kinds of evolutionary algorithm including the genetic algorithm. It is built as more of a framework which allows you to easily plug in your own selection, crossover and mutation functions.

https://github.com/deap/deap